# img preloading, queue & dequeue

Tags: jquery

I am trying to preload some images.  In a loop, I create the img nodes:

```
        var imgP = $('<img id="imgP_' + i + '">');
        imgP.on('load', function() {
            alert("Loaded: " + $(this).attr('src'));
            $("#view1").queue( function() {
                // determine where/how to display the image
                alert("DEQUEUED: " + imgP.attr('src'));
            });
        });
        imgP.attr('src',unviewedFiles[i]);
```

The first ('Loaded') alert is triggered, so I assume the innermost function has been placed on the fx queue.  I have a click handler where I dequeue:

```
function handleViewClick(event){
    $("#view1").dequeue();  // analyze and report on click.
    alert("image clicked @(" + event.clientX + "," + event.clientY +
}
```

However, although the alert in the click handler is triggered, the other alert is not.  It's my first time trying this but I thought that dequeueing would take the function which has been previously en-queue'd and run it.

Can someone help?  Thanks.

Comment: Is the `"Loaded:"` alert triggered?  P.S. I suggest using `console.log()` to debug, not `alert()`.

Comment: Uhm, what's the queue for ?

Comment: The queue is merely a way to keep track of the images that have been preloaded and are therefore available to be displayed

Comment: Okay, I don't get it, but it's probably right ?

Comment: And yes, the "Loaded:" alert (now console.log) is triggered.

Comment: There isn't enough source code here to see what went wrong. What uses handleViewClick? When is it bound? What does the loop look like?

Comment: Oops.  This code is sitting in a query tabs.  When I pulled it out on its own, it worked.  I'll rephrase the question with full info.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that this code was on a page in a dynamically loaded jquery tab. $("#view1") didn't exist when the function was enQ'd.  If "#view1" is replaced by "body" it works.